# Print total number of languages in data (Python assignment)

Tags: python, for-loop

For an assignment in my 30 days Python course i have the following:

Go to the data folder and use the [countries_data.py](https://github.com/Asabeneh/30-Days-Of-Python/blob/master/data/countries-data.py) file.

What are the total number of languages in the data?

So i have tried everything, but i cant seem to write a code that returns the total number of languages. I have gotten as far as this:

```
for language in countries:
    for key in language:
        if key == ('languages'): print (key.count('languages'))
```

But the output only shows how many times the key languages is in the file.

I Wrote:

```
for language in countries:
    for key in language:
        if key == language: print (key.items())
```

I hope that someone can give me the right script.

Comment: Put all the languages in a `set`. Then use `len(language_set)` to get the total number.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `set` to get all the unique languages in the data.

```
languages = set()

for country in countries:
    languages.update(country['languages'])

print("Total number of languages: ", len(languages))
```

Comment: it gives me the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*****\30DaysOfPython\day_2\variables.py", line 2919, in <module>
    languages.update(country.languages)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'languages'

Comment: Sorry, accidentally slipped into JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
len({language for country in countries for language in country['languages']})
```

Comment: Please provide more insight into your code

Comment: Why are you only counting the first language in each list?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
country_set = set()
for i countries_data:
    for j in i['languages']:
        country_set.add(j)
```

The complete code is shown below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5Mi0.png)

Comment: Hi min, weelcome to SO. Please do not add code as an image for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2530121). Instead, add the full code to your existing codeblock. Thanks

Comment: Please include your full code as text and follow [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) to properly format your code block.